# How to move identity related classes from the main project to the Datalayer in َ multi-layer Asp .Net Core 3.1 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm new in Asp .net Core.I created multilayer project with.net core 3.1 and I want to use Identity. I scaffolded identity on main project, A folder called Identity was created, which includes classes(Razor Pages) related to Identity. I want to move these classes to the data layer(codefirst approach). How can I do this?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, @n.e, You mean just 'pagemodel ' in a class library?

Comment: Hi. yes, in a class library

Comment: You could check the latest answer I updated.

Comment: Yes, that's separation between the UI layer (the .cshtml view file) and processing logic for the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got a lot of errors.

Comment: for example I got errors in files with the suffix cshtml.g.cs

Comment: Sorry, I'm confusing with your description. Please detail more.

Comment: Thanks. it solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 10/09/2020

1. Create **Datalayer** class library

**Setting of Datalayer**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.1.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]

2. In the `Project Reference` dialog, select the DataLayer project, and select OK.

[image]

3. Build again

### Move `.cs` to `/Data`

You could move all `*.cs` files to `Data` directory in the File Explorer. And it will move automatically in VS.

[image]